# listview trigger('create') performance issue - jqm enhancement

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have JQM application where when user clicks listview item i fetch dynamic checkbox markup and append to it. Then i call `$('#listViewItemID').trigger('create')` which is taking around  6 seconds to enhance.

I have replicated this problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/skusunam/MMbLW/1/

Once you click the button it takes around 1.4secs to just do JQM enhance. This call is making browser un-responsive. I must be missing something and really appreciate any feedback\input.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think there is nothing you can do here. However, it would be nice to open a issue to the project repository to inform of the issue.